# The default android contacts app DetailFragment query

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm wondering how the guys that developed the default contacts app achieved that highlighted, in picture with the green arrow, effect.

[image]

The blue line, is

- that just an image inside an ImageView,
- or is it some coloured padding effect for the TextView,
- or is it something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say it's simply `View` with a solid background colour and the width of `2dp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ics_blue" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_page_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_page_margin"
   />
```